# Why Weyl's (infinitesimal geometry) theory of gravity is physically unreasonable?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-gravity

It is usually [mentioned](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Classical_unified_field_theories#/Weyl.27s_infinitesimal_geometry) that Weyl theory is generalization of the Einstein’s gravity that included Electromagnetism.

In the same time, they saying that it is physically unreasonable and inconsistent with QM. Is it possible to explain in a simple way why it gives unreasonable results?

And since it is not kind of an ad-hoc generalization, but a very natural one mathematically speaking (as I understood). Then are there any particular reasons why nature still "prefers" to work by the special case (GR)?

P.S

Regarding last question: Kaluza-Klien theory dose a similar thing, also it can be quantized, however the results (particles) simply do not represent our reality, but it is dose contains some ad-hoc assumptions, what I do not see in Weyl's.

Comment: N.B. For those researching the equation, it is *not* referring to Weyl gravity, $\mathcal L \sim C^{abcd}C_{abcd}$ but rather Weyl's theory of 'infinitesimal geometry.'

Comment: Yep that can be confusing, corrected...

Answer (score 1):

I hope it is clear to OP that the validity of physical models can only be judged by experimental verification.

Weyl's theory explains electromagnetism through an extended affine connection. Parallel transport with respect to this extended connection no longer preserves the interval $g_{\mu \nu}(x) v^{\mu} v^{\nu}$ of the vector (like in General Relativity).

As a result, Weyl's theory gives a falsifiable prediction: there's gotta be time differences between the same process within the strong electromagnetic field, and in vacuum. In particular, the spectrum of Hydrogen is predicted to shift in the presence of the strong electromagnetic field. This is contrary to observations.

It was Einstein's original argument which lead him to discard Weyl's theory of gravity.

Weyl's theory is not inconsistent (at least in its classical form). It was falsified by experiment, which is the real reason for it to be considered unphysical.

Comment: Pretty clear answer, Wikipedia article spoke about inconsistency, not experimental contradiction.

Comment: @TMS my answer is based on what I heard a while ago from my professor. I don't really want to go into details with the wikipedia article, sorry.

Comment: You do not need, I just mentioned that to explain confusion reason, that is all.

Comment: Well it sounds like experiment and consistency with SR would be equivalent in this case. That time is the same In an EM field and in vacuum I am pretty sure was well known as consistent with  Maxwell. Maybe they did some experiment more accurately, but it would be nice to know what that was. The professor's word is not enough

Comment: @BobBee depends on what you mean by "consistency with SR". In the electromagnetic vacuum, the theory reduces to GR. GR has a special solution which is SR.